# Symmetries of the set of points $S$

Tags: geometry, symmetry

Consider that we have a set of points $S$ in the plane $\mathbb R^2$ or in the space $\mathbb R^3$ and we also consider the one to one mappings $f:S \to S$ which have the following property:

They maintain the distances (if $A,B \in S$ points, then $f(A),f(B)$ are also points $\in S$, and the distance of $f(A)$ from $f(B)$ is equal to the distance of $A$ from $B$), that is, $f$ is an isometry.

Then, the set of these $f$ consist of the symmetries of the set of points $S$.

Could you explain me the last sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"symmetries" are rotations, reflections, translations, and combinations of those, that map a space onto itself.

As an example, the symmetries of the square form the group $D_8$, which consists of identity, 3 rotations, and 4 reflections.

The symmetries of $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$ are the isometries of those spaces.

Comment: Are the isometries always symmetries or just at the case when $f(S)=S$ ?

Comment: @evinda: I think isometries are the same as symmetries, but $f(S)=S$ does not necessarily mean that f is either a symmetry or an isometry. As an example, a scaling (like $x \mapsto 2x$) has $f(S)=S$, but it is neither an isometry nor a symmetry.

Comment: A ok...Thank you very much!!!